# How to show just one image at a time at a set interval?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a javascript function which takes two images from div style and displays it one picture first and the other picture after the specified time.

JavaScript

```
var imageID = 0;
function changeImage (every_seconds) {
    if (!imageID) {
        document.getElementById("myimage1");
        imageID++;
    }
    if (imageID == 1) {
        document.getElementById("myimage2");
    }
}
//call same function again for x of seconds
setTimeout("changeImage(" + every_seconds + ")", ((every_seconds) * 50000000000));
}
```

HTML

```
<body style='background:black;' onload='changeimage(10)'>
    <div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='left'>
        <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage1' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/>
    </div>
    <div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='right'>
        <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage2' src='http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg'/>                                                              
    </div>
</body>
```

Please can someone help how to get just a single image at a time and disappear the other one at the specified interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following if you want to try in vanilla JS without using library like JQuery

```js
var imageID=0;
function changeImage(){
  var img1 = document.getElementById("myimage1");
  var img2 = document.getElementById("myimage2");   
  if(imageID %2 == 0){
    img1.style.display = 'block';
    img2.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    img2.style.display = 'block';
    img1.style.display = 'none';
  }
  imageID++;
}

//call same function again for x of seconds
setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

```html
<body style='background:black;'>
  <div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;'>
    <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage1' style='display:none' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/>
    <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage2' style='display:none' src='http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg'/>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are two images placed inside the same container. Both of which are hidden when the page loads. You don't need the onload event handler in the body since the JS will get executed after the HTML loads. That time it will invoke the setInterval method that will change the image every 1 second.

Comment: Is it a convention to write <div> at the top? Thanks.

Comment: Any HTML on the page preferably should appear before any inline JavaScript so that user can see the content of the as quickly as possible. Otherwise the embedded JS will halt the browser rendering and user will see empty or partially rendered page based on where is your script is. That is the reason I removed the JS from head tag and added after the markup ends.

Comment: It's better style to write `setInterval(changeImage, 1000)‘. No need for the anonymous function.

Comment: @Diptendu - In your example I am getting both the images at the same time. How can I get only one initially? Thanks.

Comment: @deep You should not be getting anything initially since both the images have "display:none". It will be a black screen and then one image appears. If you want one image to appear instead of blank screen, remove the display: none from the style of second img.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can hide the image at a specified time using jQuery setTimeout function,
```

Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/kdk6kkLv/

```
$(function() {
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(hidden).hide()
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is not a jQuery function. Also, you can write that as `setTimeout($(".hidden").hide, 2000)`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest changing the HTML a bit by giving ids to the container divs too. Also let myDiv2 be hidden at first. We can then use a built-in function in javascript called `setInterval()` to which we pass the function to execute as the first parameter and the time in milliseconds between two consecutive executions as the second parameter.

`setInterval()` method calls a function repeatedly at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```
<div id="myDiv1" style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='left'>
    <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage1' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/>
</div>

<div id="myDiv2" style='display:none; position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='right'>
    <img width='600px' height='500px' id='myimage2' src='http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg'/>                                                              
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {            //setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
    var div1 = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");

    if(div2.display = '') {         //This executes when div2 is visible (and div1 is hidden)
        div1.display = '';          //This makes div1 (and myimage1) visible
        div2.display = 'none';      //This hides div2 (and myimage2)
    } else {                        //This executes when div1 is visible (and div2 is hidden)
        div2.display = '';
        div1.display = 'none';
    }
}, 5000);                           //You can give time in milliseconds between each change instead of 5000 here. 5000ms = 5s.
```

You can look up `setInterval()` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Image Slideshow using `setinterval` for hide one and show another image.

### You can try out below mentioned simple way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var image=document.getElementById("aaa");
    var img_array=[...];
    var index=0;
    var interval = 2000;
    function slide() {
        image.src = img_array[index++%img_array.length];
    }
    setInterval(slide, interval);
}
```

### Another option for the same:

Instead of `setInterval(slide,2000);` use below code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    slide();
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval)
}, interval);
```